# Sacar en una misma query SQL el count de diferentes valores y el porcentaje sobre el total de registros

Tags: sql, porcentaje, hive

Quisiera saber como puedo combinar hacer para sacar el porcentaje en el mismo resultado de la consulta de una query.  Me explico:
Tengo esta query:

```
select tbl.ecnmc as clave, count(ecnmc) as valor 
from schema.tbl
where id_bar = "ID04"
group by ecnmc
```

Que me éste resultado:

```
clave   valor
K2       21 
K8       8
K9       19
K5       2
```

Piues bien, por otro lado  tengo la query del total de valores

```
select count(*) from schema.tbl;
```

Lo que quiero es que al final se me muestre de este modo:

```
clave   valor   total    porcentaje
K2       21      50         42
K8       8       50         16
K9       19      50         38
K5       2       50          4
```

Lo que se me ocurre es sacar el porcentaje por de medio de la formula de la regla de 3 (valor*100/total), pero claro necesito antes sacar el total,  ¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?.

Gracias.

Comment: Qué has intentado?

Comment: ¿Qué motor de base de datos estas usando? indícalo por favor en las etiquetas

Comment: Hola, no habia intentado mucho porque no sé muy bien como atacarlo, pero si había intentado poner en el Select un count(*) pero claro los filtros del Where me afectarían.

Comment: La base de datos que estoy usando es Hive a través de Beeline, soy nuevo en este tipo de herramientas.  Es acceder a Hive a través de una pantalla negra de comandos, no sé si me explico.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una opción es realizar un `CROSS JOIN` con una subquery que retorne el total de registros.

```
SELECT tbl.ecnmc AS clave, 
       count(ecnmc) AS valor, 
       MAX(total.cantidad) AS total,
       count(ecnmc) * 100 / MAX(total.cantidad) AS porcentaje
       
FROM schema.tbl
CROSS JOIN (SELECT count(*) AS cantidad FROM schema.tbl) AS total
WHERE id_bar = "ID04"
GROUP BY ecnmc;
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias, era lo que estaba buscando.

Comment: De nada @JoseMariaAcevedoReinoso!!!